# Problems in modules during importing test suite file from Eclipse to intelliJ

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng

Module NAME: invalid item 'org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER' in the dependencies list

Module NAME: invalid item 'org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER' in the dependencies list

[image]

While importing from eclipse  to intellij these two problems occures in  PROJECT SETTINGS--> MODULES --> DEPENDENCIES

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA you should use File > New Project, Import project from external model.

Also can you check that Eclipse plug-in is enabled in Settings > Plugins

Comment: Also, you might need to remove these two dependencies and might have to configure these yourself.